# MS Access - searching for better method to create and edit records

Tags: ms-access

I have made a database that I use at work for tracking tags that get signed out. The way I currently have it is I created a table that has 100 records manually entered already. Field Name "TagNumber" 1 to 100. There are several other fields for every record that is currently blank.

A user will have access to a form that they will select a tag number from the "TagNumber" dropdown list. Doing this will allow them to fill in the other fields with the correct info for that tag. When finished they will click a save and exit button that will modify that record they just put the info in for. It will also update a Field named "SignedOut" it is a data type Yes/No field. Once the user has signed out that tag number it will no longer show up on the dropdown list when someone else goes to sign out a tag.

On the same form there is a "SignIn" dropdown list that only shows the tags that are checked yes in the "SignedOut" Field. When a user selects a tag to be signed they enter their name and date and click save and exit. Clicking the save and exit button will run a macro that copies all the data on that single record to another table for tracking purposes. It also sets all the fields back to blank except the "TagNumber" field. This allows another user to sign out that tag again.

examples of my tables:

[Nothing signed out yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjeZ8.png)

[Tag 4 signed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYTjJ.png)

Now my issue I am running into is If I provide this to another section they have different tag numbers and I don't want to have to go to the table and physically change every tag number. Is there a way I can auto populate the list with different tag numbers? or is there a way I should be doing this that is completely different from the way I am doing it?

Thanks for any info you can provide.

Comment: Why prefill tag numbers? Why isn't user just entering tag number into new record row? What are these tags? They have number printed on them?

Comment: Why define the tag number up front? Why not use an identity column, or a computed column based on an identity column, and give the generated tag number after check out?

Comment: The tags have a number physically printed on them. The user will physically take this tag and I use this database to track who, where and when it was signed out and singed back in.

I defined the tag number upfront because that was the only why I could figure out how to do what I wanted. Do you have anymore info on this computed column idea? I will also google these ideas and see if I can get them to work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your concept, but my recent article may provide some methods or ideas you can take advantage of: [Sequential Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33069/Sequential-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

Comment: Sounds like MS Lending Library template could be adapted to your situation. I would not have tag numbers prefilled. I would have a combobox for user selection of tag. If they type a tag number not yet in db use combobox NotInList event to create new record 'on the fly' during data entry. Split the database - backend on network server and copies of frontend distributed to all users.

Comment: @June7 I do have the database split into front and backend. I will look more into the method you have described

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for the link I will have a look at it .